# Python Tuple to dict to JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary

my data

```
(('check_kvserver_mem_4500000', 2737L), 
 ('check_ethstatus', 250L), 
 ('check_ddos', 229L), 
 ('check_coredump', 193L),
 ('check_robot', 174L),
 ('check_disk_90_95', 155L))
```

into this:`print json.dumps(data)`

```
[["check_kvserver_mem_4500000", 2737], 
 ["check_ethstatus", 250],
 ["check_ddos", 229],
 ["check_coredump", 193], 
 ["check_disk_90_95", 155]]
```

I want data like

```
{["check_kvserver_mem_4500000", 2737],
 ["check_ethstatus", 250]
 ["check_ddos", 229], 
 ["check_coredump", 193], 
 ["check_disk_90_95", 155]}
```

or

```
 {"check_kvserver_mem_4500000":2737,
  "check_ethstatus":250,
  "check_ddos":229, 
  "check_coredump":193,
  "check_disk_90_95":155}
```

Comment: Your desired output is not valid json.

Comment: Also, please format your code neatly. It's very hard to read it when it is just one long line.

Answer (score 4):

You want a JSON Object as a result but your data has no key/value structure. So `json.dumps(data)` is doing the right thing in generating a JSON List, not an Object. A Python tuple of tuples can not be matched on an invalid JSON Object.

**Edit**

After you changed your question (and deleted my *beautiful* edits while doing this), your question can be answered.

```
data = (('check_kvserver_mem_4500000', 2737L),
        ('check_ethstatus', 250L),
        ('check_ddos', 229L),
        ('check_coredump', 193L),
        ('check_robot', 174L),
        ('check_disk_90_95', 155L))
print json.dumps(dict(data))
```

Result is:

```
'{"check_disk_90_95": 155, "check_coredump": 193, "check_robot": 174,
  "check_kvserver_mem_4500000": 2737, "check_ddos": 229, "check_ethstatus": 250}'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 print json.dumps(dict(data))
 {"check_disk_90_95": 155,
  "check_coredump": 193,
  "check_robot": 174,
  "check_kvserver_mem_4500000": 2737,
  "check_ddos": 229,
  "check_ethstatus": 250}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = dict((('check_kvserver_mem_4500000', 2737L), ('check_ethstatus', 250L), ('check_ddos', 229L), ('check_coredump', 193L), ('check_robot',
174L), ('check_disk_90_95', 155L)))

import json 

print json.dumps(x, indent = 5)
```

Returns

```
{
     "check_disk_90_95": 155, 
     "check_coredump": 193, 
     "check_robot": 174, 
     "check_kvserver_mem_4500000": 2737, 
     "check_ddos": 229, 
     "check_ethstatus": 250
}
```