# How to turn a list of tuples into a JSON object with duplicate keys?

Tags: python, json

[JSON allows duplicate keys in objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21832701/96588). The Python JSON parser by default ignores any but the last duplicate, but has a [mechanism](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#repeated-names-within-an-object) for overriding this behaviour which I need to use to detect and report such issues. Basically, the code will be something like [`load(file_pointer, object_pairs_hook=report_duplicates)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14902564/96588).

To test this behaviour I need to create a JSON object with duplicate keys. Is there some simple way to do that in Python 3.8 *without hand-coding the JSON string?* For example, could I convert `[("x": 1), ("x": 2)]` into a JSON string `{"x": 1, "x": 2}`? (The order doesn't matter.) The reason is that I need the JSON object to have a specific structure, so the test will be noisy if I have to type the whole thing into a string.

Since this is specifically about duplicate keys I can't use [solutions like `dumps(dict(…))`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11735184/96588).

---

So far I have this:

```py
class KeyValueList(list):
    pass


class KeyValueListEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def iterencode(self, obj: Any, _one_shot: bool = False) -> Iterator[str]:
        if isinstance(obj, KeyValueList):
            yield "{"

            max_index = len(obj) - 1
            for index, (key, value) in enumerate(obj):
                yield JSONEncoder.encode(self, key)
                yield self.key_separator
                yield JSONEncoder.encode(self, value)
                if index != max_index:
                    yield self.item_separator

            yield "}"
        else:
            for chunk in JSONEncoder.iterencode(self, obj, _one_shot=_one_shot):
                yield chunk
```

This works if the top-level object being serialized is a `KeyValueList`, but if the `KeyValueList` is nested in another data structure it's serialized as a `list`:

```
>>> dumps(KeyValueList((("x", 1), ("x", 2))), cls=KeyValueListEncoder)
'{"x": 1, "x": 2}'
>>> dumps({"foo": KeyValueList((("x", 1), ("x", 2)))}, cls=KeyValueListEncoder)
'{"foo": [["x", 1], ["x", 2]]}'
```

(I can't override `default` as per the documentation because [`default` is only called when a type is not already serializable](https://bugs.python.org/issue40475#msg367915).)

Comment: You probably will have to create a custom `list` type (to not conflate with standard handling of `list`) to store the list of 2-tuples, and follow the solution presented in [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable).

Comment: Clearly you can create a dict that is close to your needs with, say, "x1" and "x2", then bring it in to a text editor and patch it.  That has to be the easiest path.

Comment: @TimRoberts That doesn't make for nice code though, and doesn't scale.

Comment: I disagree, the code would be MUCH nicer.  You could, I suppose, use a magic marker for your duplicates, like `x__1__`, `x__2__`, and so on.  Then, after the `dumps` you could use simple string substitution to remove the magic markers.